# Slurm - ambiguous redirect

Tags: bash, slurm

I'm not certain what the problem is with my slurm script - the error messages that I'm receiving are ambiguous redirect for my $input and command not found for when I'm trying to define my variables.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=gim
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#SBATCH --ntasks=20
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH -o output_%A_%a.out #Standard Output
#SBATCH -e output_%A_%a.err #Standard Error

module load program

input= gim${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}.gjf
output= gim${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}.log

program $input > $output
```

The way I run it is:

```
sbatch --array=1-500 ./slurm.job
```

Comment: `input= foo` is running `foo` as a command with `input` set as an environment variable with an empty value for the duration of that single execution only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace matters:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ...etc...

input=gim${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}.gjf
output=gim${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}.log

program "$input" > "$output"
```

Note the lack of spaces surrounding the `=` sign for the assignments. Whitespace matters:

```
foo = bar # this runs "foo" with "=" as the first argument and "bar" as the second
foo =bar  # this runs "foo" with "=bar" as its first argument
foo= bar  # this runs "bar" as a command with "foo" as an empty string in its environment
foo=bar   # this assigns the value "bar" to the shell variable "foo"
```

Comment: thanks, another lesson learned :)

Comment: BTW, consider making a habit of using http://shellcheck.net/ (also an installable tool), which will identify this class of bug (and others) automatically.